# Axis2 adb and minInclusive = -2147483648

Tags: java, xsd, overflow, apache-axis

I have an XSD with this type

```
<xs:simpleType name="dec_number_def">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
       <xs:minInclusive value="-2147483648"/>
       <xs:maxInclusive value="2147483647"/>
   </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
```

And I think is ok, because for java data type **int** the max value is 2147483647 and the min value is -2147483648

But the axis stub reject a value like 3

When I created the stub with axis2 ADB 1.7.5 and 1.7.6 I get:

```
    /**
     * Auto generated setter method
     * @param param Dec_number_def
     */
    public void setDec_number_def(int param) {
        if (org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.compare(
                    param, "2147483647") <= 0) {
            this.localDec_number_def = param;
        } else {
            throw new java.lang.RuntimeException(
                "Input values do not follow defined XSD restrictions");
        }

        if (org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.compare(
                    param, "-2147483648") >= 0) {
            this.localDec_number_def = param;
        } else {
            throw new java.lang.RuntimeException(
                "Input values do not follow defined XSD restrictions");
        }
    }
```

If parameter is a positive number, I get a negative number with compare function

```
compare(3, "-2147483648") = -2147483645 !!!!
```

because the funcion compare is

```
public static int More compare(int intValue, String value) {
   return intValue - Integer.parseInt(value);
}
```

And

```
3 - (-2147483648) = 3 + 2147483648 = 2147483651  OVERFLOW !!!
then -2147483645 is returned and the validation is ERROR
```

Then this is an Axis error?  or is a XSD error?

Comment: Your minInclusive and maxInclusive bounds are redundant, since the values given are already the bounds of the xs:int datatype.  (That is, your type is a vacuous restriction of xs:int.)  Why are you using "compare" and what results are you expecting from it?

Comment: Yes, the XSD is redundant, but is my input, and I am not using "compare" is the ADB code generator who created de code "compare"  inside the  stub.